# Can anyone suggest a good book for a beginner in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suggestion of a new beginners book for Ruby?

Comment: beginner in Ruby or beginner in programming ? What languages do you know ?

Comment: by the way, have you looked ad that list : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549394/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-ruby ?

Comment: http://humblelittlerubybook.com/ in case you're beginner in programming :)

Answer (score 7):

My favorite Ruby language book is  [The Ruby Programming Language](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516178) by David Flanagan & Yukihiro Matsumoto
Also see [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/)

Answer (score 3):

[why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

- [Pickaxe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356085)
- [The well-grounded Rubyist](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988657)
- [Beginning Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223634)

Answer (score 0):

you read [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) first, and then the [meta programming ruby book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476).